# Checking Each Cart Heading Items For Specific Style Names

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, foreach

I am in the process of developing an AB Test for an e-commerce cart page. We have a list of about 100 stylenames that we are not going to be accepting returns on.

We have messaging displayed on those particular styles' product display pages, but we would also like to have this message reinforced on the cart page if any product in the cart matches the list of stylenames that qualify.

I have started by creating an array variable of all qualified stylenames (shortened here for example). I then loop through each cart item heading tag & check the .text() of that element. IF the .text() matches one of the stylenames I am looking for, I would then want to go ahead and append the message below the cart item heading tag.

Here is the script I have written, however, I don't see the result expected when running this locally in my devtools snippet:

```js
var styleList = ['Astawia Loafer','Another Style','So On','So Forth'];
var finalSaleMessage = '<span><strong>Final sale! </strong>No returns on our best deals.</span>'

function checkStyleName(value,arr){
    var result = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        var name = arr[i];
        if(name == value){
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

$('.crt-heading--item').each(function(){
    if (checkStyleName($('.crt-heading--item').text(),styleList) == true) {
        // append the message
    }
    
})
```

Any input here from the community would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you would need further information.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share one style format in your question. i.e how the style is displayed in the source?

Comment: Sure thing @LearningEveryday -- each item in the cart has an h3 tag like such:

`<h3 class="crt-heading--item">ALDO Astawia Loafer (Women's)</h3>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be simplified a little.
No need to send array everytime.
Usage of includes.
Looks like the text is in the format of `BRAND PRODUCT_NAME CATEGORY`. You may want to split or do something to get the `PRODUCT_NAME`.
Usage of `this` as pointed out by `devmiguelopz`

```js
    var styleList = ['Astawia Loafer','Another Style','So On','So Forth'];
    var finalSaleMessage = '<span><strong>Final sale! </strong>No returns on our best deals.</span>'
   
    // OLD SUGGESTION
    /*
        $('.crt-heading--item').each(function(){
        if (styleList.includes($(this).text()) {
            // append the message
        }
*/
    // This will iterate on the elements
    $('.crt-heading--item').each(function(){
        // Iterate on the styleList
        var styleListLength = styleList.length;
        for(var i = 0, i < styleListLength; i++){
           // Check if the name has entry from styleList
           if($(this).text().includes(styleList[i])){
              // DO STUFF
           }
        }
    
})
// We re running a loop inside a loop in this case.
// There may be better ways of doing this with .some/.filter/.map
```

Check here for what `.includes` can do for you :   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: This is great -- a bit more concise & should still accomplish what I am looking for. Much appreciated. I am trying this now

Comment: Thanks again for your help. looks like right now I have to match the ENTIRE product name, for example. I am only alerting true if I match:

"ALDO Astawia Loafer (Women's)"

instead of "Astawia Loafer"

I tried to adjust the conditional statement to :

`if (styleList.includes($(this).text().split())){
        alert("TRUE");
    }`

But no luck there. Any other suggestions would be immensely helpful, but no worries if not -- you've helped a great deal so far!

Comment: I have improved it! Please check if this helps. Ask questions if necessary!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you go through all the elements of a certain class and don't refer to every single one of them.

```js
var styleList = ['Astawia Loafer','Another Style','So On','So Forth'];
var finalSaleMessage = '<span><strong>Final sale! </strong>No returns on our best deals.</span>'

function checkStyleName(value,arr){
    var result = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        var name = arr[i];
        if(name == value){
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
$('.crt-heading--item').each(function(){
    if (checkStyleName($(this).text(),styleList) == true) {
        // append the message
        //test
        alert($(this).text())
    }
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class= "crt-heading--item">Astawia Loafer</li>
  <li class= "crt-heading--item">Astawia Loafer</li>
  <li class= "crt-heading--item">3</li>
  <li class= "crt-heading--item">So On</li>
  <li class= "crt-heading--item">5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ahhhh okay -- this is super helpful. I am going to check on this now, but this most likely will be a viable solution for me.

Appreciate the help here!

Comment: hmm -- doesn't seem to work on my cart page as is. here is the markup of the cart items:

`<div class="grd-small-7 grd-columns">
      
      <div class="crt-text-xs crt-quick-ship-notice">
        <div class="crt-ordr-by-ship">Order by 3 PM Eastern, ships same day!</div></div>
      
        <a href="/aldo-kaicien-ankle-boot/880053/1968295" data-ol-has-click-handler="">
          <h3 class="crt-heading--item">ALDO Kaicien Ankle Boot (Women's)</h3>
        </a>
        
    </div>`